# fosuserbundle bad credentials

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I'm new with FOSUserBundle, I've realize the authentication process before without this bundle and I'm trying make the same with him. The problem is that I have configured as the documentation said, and when I'm try login in the application I receive a exception Bad Credentials when really the user and pass are correct. I hope any kind of help to resolve my problem. Sorry for my English, thanks

**EDIT with security.yml**

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                logout: true
                anonymous: true

    access_control:

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Comment: Well, we are not going very far with so few explanations. Start by posting your app/config/security.yml please

Comment: Did you activate your user ?

Comment: Yes, the problem was in the configuration of the form, I forget to add _password as name, sorry and thanks